# For automorphism T, prove identity map is in span of ${T,T^2,T^3, ...}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, $T$ be an automorphism with an inverse $S$ s.t. $ST=1_v$. Can I say that $1_v$ is in the span of $\{T^i\;|\; i=1,2,3 ...\}$? 
I feel this is right but I can find a way to reason it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no - pick a permutation $\pi$ of $\mathbb{N}$ of infinite order$^*$, look at the vector space $V=\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}F$ with standard basis $\{e_i: \in\mathbb{N}\}$, and consider the automorphism $T$ generated by $e_i\mapsto e_{\pi(i)}$.

But! There is a natural additional hypothesis you can make about your vector space, which will make your statement true. Can you see from this example what that hypothesis should be?

---

$^*$It's a good exercise to show that such a permutation exists. Here's a hint: partition $\mathbb{N}$ into sets $A_i$, with $\vert A_i\vert=i$, for $i\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $i$, let $\pi_i$ be a permutation of $A_i$ of order $i$ - just a cycle of length $i$. Now, what happens when we combine the $\pi_i$s?

Comment: So the statement would be true if V is finite dimensional?? Is there a way to reason this?

Comment: @MorganRodgers It doesn't - this is just an *example* of an automorphism which doesn't satisfy the OP's conditions.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Oh, I see the confusion. That's a good point - I didn't mean to imply that this was the *only* way to get "bad" automorphisms. Indeed, you're quite right - if I recall correctly, the proof that finite-dimensional vector spaces don't have "bad" automorphisms actually takes some work (specifically, the work of showing that minimal polynomials exist etc.).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Nah, it doesn't take that much work since $\{T^i\}$ itself is confined to a vector space of dimension $n^2$ and thus contains some non-trivial linear relation, meaning $T$ satisfies some non-zero polynomial.  We get an inferior degree bound this way, but the existence of a minimal polynomial isn't needed for the argument to go through.

Comment: @ErickWong "Some work" is relative of course - I just meant that, in some sense, the existence of counterexamples in the infinite case is 'just logic,' while the proof for the finite case actually requires us to prove things about the set of linear transformations. (Please don't ask me to try to make that distinction precise. :P) You're right that we don't actually need the minimal polynomial, though.

Answer (score 2):

In finite dimension your statement is true. Take the minimal polynomial $P_T(x)$ of the application $T$. $x$ does not divide $P_T$ because $T$ is invertible and so it's injective. You have that $P_T(T)=0$, so something like the following holds ($c \neq 0$)
$$a_nT^n+...+a_1T+c=0.$$

From there, dividing by $c$, you can easily derive an expression for the identity in function of $T$.

Comment: But you're assuming there is a minimal polynomial, which is not true in arbitrary vector spaces (it is true if $V$ is finite-dimensional).

Comment: Yes, this works only in finite dimension, but I thought it was interesting to see how this can be done explicitely.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you actually mentioned this as an assumption :).

Comment: Thank you I think I get what I need!!